# OpenJDK 7 GCM support like in Oracle JDK?

Tags: encryption, java-7, aes-gcm

Oracle JDK 7 supports GCM since version 7u191 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u191-bugfixes-4489527.html)

In the openJDK Bugtracker, they mention they fixed it. (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200684)

But I checked with the latest OpenJDK 7 241 version, and still no AES GCM Cipher Suites. I need it in an old application for TLS 1.2 support with the GCM cipher suites. OpenJDK 7 btw. supports TLS 1.2 by default since a longer time.

I even checked the source code, but cannot find the backport commits. Is it an Oracle-Only fix?

Comment: I have this exact same question and can't find anything. My best guess is that they approved and checked in the fix, but never released it, since they list it as "Fixed" in their bug tracker but it doesn't have a release.

Comment: This is the issue in their bug tracker:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180834

Comment: you can try [zulu JDK 7](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-7-lts&package=jdk), I test 7u285, it has GCM support.